# Select a column with a keyword name

Tags: mysql, sql, keyword

I have a table named 'test'

It contains a column named 'AND'

For that I use the following queries

```
insert into test values ('a','abc');
insert into test values ('b','def');
```

Now I want to select my 'AND' column from the 'test' table

The query `select AND from test;` wont work because AND is keyword

I tried

```
select "AND" from test;
select 'AND' from test;
```

Both queries return the wrong results as show below

[image]

How can I select my 'AND' column?

Comment: Hmm, am I the only one who finds it strange that OP didn't make the connection between the backticks in the `create table` and those that are needed in the `select`? :-) And, for the record, `and` is a rather poor name for a column, not because it's a keyword, but because it's not really descriptive.

Comment: Yes, Its strongly recommended for avoiding to use the reserved key word .

Comment: I know its better to avoid such column names.I dont want to use such column names. I just want to know how to get it.  I used ' symbol instead of ` thats why i got wrong results. Anyway In sql server if you use select "name" from aa; then you will get contents in the name column. But in mysql if you use " or ' in column names you wont get correct result.

Answer (score 30):

use `backtick` to escape keyword instead. just like how you created your table. using double quote or single quote will parse it into `string` that is why you're getting two records of `and`

```
select `AND` from test;
```

Answer (score 7):

1. Don't create columns with a name that is a keyword.
2. If you do create a column with such a name, use backticks (MySQL only) or double quotes (SQL standard) to enclose the name.  I'm not certain whether you need to switch on some mechanism to have double quotes work in MySQL.  This creates a 'delimited identifier'.

   ```
   SELECT `AND` AS a, "AND" AS b
     FROM test;
   ```

See also:

- [What does the SQL Standard say about back-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573922/what-does-the-sql-standard-say-about-usage-of/10574031#10574031)
- [SQL standard to escape column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names)

Comment: Let's say we want to use AND (or another reserved word) to the right of AS? Backticks aren't working. *update* Using double quotes around the AS:ed name works.

Answer (score 2):

Its a SO old question and solved. [Read here more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords).

But still you can Try this :

```
select your_tablename.column_name from table_name;
```

Your code :-

```
select test.AND from test;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use reserved word as column, you must use backtick around the reserved word column.....

In your case, you have to do like this:

```
select `AND' from test;
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `count` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `AND` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
----^---^ Why do you use `backtick` (`) in CREATE TABLE statement?
)
```

Same way you need to use `backtick` in `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT `AND` FROM test;
-------^---^-----------
```

See [MySQL: Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use select setement using ""  it select a given sting 
so you have to give a column name like 
in mssql you have to use

```
select [AND] from test;
```

or in mysql syntex
 select `AND` from test;

Comment: No, no, no, a thousand times, no. This will choke your SQL analyser, unless it's incredibly intelligent and can figure out what that and means based on context (none I know of can do this).

Comment: yup you are right its my mistake i edited this i just forgot and reserved keyword