# Error 1064 using mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to use mysql 5.1 with python 2.6.6 and I'm getting the following error.
code :

```
   query = "INSERT INTO present_list SET from='a', to='b'" 
   print query
   cur.execute(query)
```

error :

```
   Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from='a', to='b'' at line 1
```

Can somebody understand what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please, learn SQL and Syntex then work on :
Your answer is:

For Insert Data into table
============================    
query = "INSERT INTO present_list(from,to) values('a'.'b')"; 
       print query
       cur.execute(query)

For Update Data into table
============================

query = "Update present_list set from='a', to='b'"; 
       print query
       cur.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the backstroke in from and to like :

```
INSERT INTO present_list SET `from`='a', `to`='b
```

Since from is a keyword in mysql

Answer (score 2):

Put a back strike before from. `From` is one of MySQL's [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

```
query = "INSERT INTO present_list (`from`, `to`) VALUES ('a', 'b')" 
print query
cur.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

`from` and `to` are mysql reserved words. So if you want to use them as normal names please use backtick(`) symbol around reserved word. For more info please goto
[Select a column with a keyword name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400735/select-a-column-with-a-keyword-name)