# Why can't I insert this into MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I probably made a stupid error on my syntax for the query, but I can't seam to fix it. Here is the query my program tries to execute:

```
INSERT INTO filez (
  filename,
  uploadedby,
  dateuploaded,
  public,
  FileSize,
  FileTransferSize,
  key,
  bytes
)
VALUES(
  'tacct/tesABCscdsdasdasdD.testtest',
  'tacct',
  '%27 %December %2012, %7:%32:%15%AM',
  1,
  7,
  7,
  '`',
  'TestDoc'
)
```

And here's the mysql_error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, bytes) VALUES('tacct/tesABCscdsdasdasdD.testtest', 'tacct', '%27 %D' at line 1

I did `mysql_real_escape_string()` on EVERYTHING except the FileSize and FileTransferSize in the query. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: please provide your table creation query

Comment: I wonder if the keyword `KEY` is confusing it. Try wrapping `key` in backquotes?

Comment: ‍`key` is a reserved word in MySql

Comment: @Tommy3244: Should you also tag the question `keyboard`, as you used a keyboard to type the query? And `cheese-sandwich` to ensure we know where you got the energy to move your fingers?

Comment: (Aside: a good way to check for this problem is to modify your query to insert the smallest number of columns possible, then add new columns until the error re-appears).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - the PHP tag may be justifiable in this case, since `mysql_real_escape_string` is explicitly mentioned. Please consider being kinder to new members - this is a perfectly acceptable question.

Comment: @halfer: But it didn't need to be - we are given a MySQL query, not a PHP statement. This is a perfect _MySQL-only_ question with no need to cloud it with other, irrelevant technologies. And please do not mistake my attempts to teach SO newcomers how to write better questions for "unkindness" simply because I did not use some childish emoticon: :)

Comment: @halfer: (And, strictly speaking, this question is far _too localised_ for SO, but I answered it because I'm feeling _kind_.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error tells you that the error happens at the text `key`, and it's quite correct: [`key` is a reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Where you use it as a field name, you *must* enclose it in backticks (`); it's a good general practice anyway.

So:

```
INSERT INTO `filez` (
  `filename`,
  `uploadedby`,
  `dateuploaded`,
  `public`,
  `FileSize`,
  `FileTransferSize`,
  `key`,
  `bytes`
)
VALUES(
  'tommy3244/tesABCscdsdasdasdD.testtest',
  'tommy3244',
  '%27 %December %2012, %7:%32:%15%AM',
  1,
  7,
  7,
  '`',
  'TestDoc'
)
```

Comment: @Tommy3244: Preferably, enclose _all_ field names in backticks (_not_ "quotations"). That gives you consistency and prevents you from running into the problem again. It also aids syntax highlighting and probably makes parsing marginally faster.

Answer (score 4):

try using following query

```
INSERT INTO filez (filename, uploadedby, dateuploaded, public, FileSize, FileTransferSize, `key`, bytes) VALUES
('tommy3244/tesABCscdsdasdasdD.testtest', 'tommy3244', '%27 %December %2012, %7:%32:%15%AM', 
1, 7, 7, '`', 'TestDoc')
```

`key` is keyword so you have to use backticks as i used above.
For more info check following question too 
[Select a column with a keyword name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400735/select-a-column-with-a-keyword-name)

Comment: A good answer _explains_ the problem. Also your suggested query is highly inconsistent.

Answer (score 4):

**key is a reserved word** and you can not use it in column name without using backtics. try this

```
INSERT INTO filez (`filename`, `uploadedby`, `dateuploaded`, `public`, `FileSize`, `FileTransferSize`, `key`, `bytes`) VALUES('tommy3244/tesABCscdsdasdasdD.testtest', 'tommy3244', '%27 %December %2012, %7:%32:%15%AM', 1, 7, 7, '`', 'TestDoc')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 INSERT INTO `filez` (`filename`, `uploadedby`, `dateuploaded`, 
                    `public`, `FileSize`, `FileTransferSize`, 
                     `key`, `bytes`) 
        VALUES('tommy3244/tesABCscdsdasdasdD.testtest',   'tommy3244', 
                '%27 %December %2012, %7:%32:%15%AM', 1, 7, 7, '`', 'TestDoc')
```

ok,

`syntax to use near 'key, bytes)`  both are reserve words, Good practice is always use ` sign for user defined identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

`KEY` is reserved key word for mysql

try other column name or make backticks like that ``

Answer (score 0):

The issue is key is the reserved keyword of mysql , you can't use it as column name, if you really want then enclose it inside backtick character

`key`