# Yahoo YQL API - How to select a JSON field whose name is a reserved YQL keywords?

Tags: json, select, field, yql, yahoo-api

For example, I got following JSON from a URL

```
{ "time": "2014-05-10 06:23:36 UTC", 
  "values": [
    {
      "time_timetable_utc": "2014-05-10T06:25:00Z",
      "time_realtime_utc": null,
      "flags": ""
    },
    {
      "time_timetable_utc": "2014-05-10T06:45:00Z",
      "time_realtime_utc": null,
      "flags": ""
    },
  ]
}
```

This will work on YQL

```
select time from json where url="{url}"
```

It will return me only time field

```
{"time": "2014-05-10 06:23:36 UTC"}
```

But if I only want to get "values" array field with following

```
select values from json where url="{url}"
```

I will get this error message

```
Query syntax error(s) [line 1:7 expecting fields_or_star got 'values']
```

**Just want to ask is that possible to select a JSON field whose name is a reserved Yahoo YQL keywords?**

I know this will work

```
select * from json where url="{url}" and itemPath="json.values"
```

But is that possible to do it **without using "itemPath" condition**?

How to escape reserved word like "values" in YQL select?

Comment: Any reason for not wanting to use itemPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just want to ask is that possible to select a field names "values"?

No. (Sorry!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, if this's true. I hope Yahoo consider fix this problem. I know YQL is not actually SQL. But all major database are allow user use reserved word as column name, even that is not recommended. See also
[MySQL Select a column with a keyword name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400735/select-a-column-with-a-keyword-name)