# not creating Mysql img containing table

Tags: mysql-error-1064

```
 create table employee
-> (
-> emp_id int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> full_name varchar(50),
-> dob date,
-> job_dep varchar(50),
-> email_id varchar(50),
-> cont_no int(10),
-> add varchar(50),
-> emp_img longblob NOT NULL,/*for passport size image*/
-> a_img longblob NOT NULL,/*for adhar image*/
-> primary key(emp_id)
-> );
```

while creating this table showing error in wamp's mysql console:-

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add varchar(50),
emp_img longblob NOT NULL,
a_img longblob NOT NULL,
primary key' at line 9

Answer (score 0):

[ADD is a reserved MySQL keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) and thus cannot be used as column name unless escaped with backticks as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12400750/7034621).