# Android / SQLite - backticks, single quotes or double quotes?

Tags: android, sqlite

Suppose I had a method like this...

```
long getNumItemsFromDb() {
SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
try {
    String query = "SELECT " + COL_NAME +
                    " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                    " WHERE " + COL_NAME + " = ?";
    String[] args = new String[] {"whatever"};
    return DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, query, args);
} finally {
    db.close();
}
```

}

...but it's possible that, for example, `String COL_NAME = "select";` and `String TABLE_NAME = "from";` - which is going to break the query. So, I'd obviously need to surround those values in my `query` String with either backticks, single quotes or double quotes - but which of these is the best practice for Android / SQLite?

NB - I have simplified my query String above to make this question simpler and more to the point. So, in reality, I do need to create the SQL manually like this rather than using one of the helper methods in Android.

NB2 - I have seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573922/what-does-the-sql-standard-say-about-usage-of-backtick) but the questions/answers do not address SQLite and Android.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say go with the standard.

The ANSI standard is double quotes for quoting fields/identifiers, and [that works well on SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/db12b/2).

Note that some other RDBMS's [may need some help to follow the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992403/477878), but following it will allow your SQL to run unchanged on as many RDBMS's/platforms as possible.

Comment: I use [some thing] (braces) in Access, SQL Server and SQLite without any problem.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Yes, square brackets work in some RDBMS', but they're not standardised so will not work in - for example - Oracle, MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: ... just the ones I never tested them on... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use androids class `SQLitedatabase` you could just simply use the `query` method and not worry if your selection string contains any of the identifiers.

Though when using FTS tables with MATCH identifier I noticed that you must surround the searchable string with percent signs like this: `"%"+str+"%"`, otherwise it only matches up until a space.