# SQL import into PostgreSQL 8.4.20 fails with syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I exported SQL file with data from existing Mysql database. Now I am trying to import it in PostgrSQL database.

I tried to use phpPgAdmin import field. I executed this SQL because I have already created my tables.

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `ancestry`, `ancestry_depth`, `priority`) VALUES
(1, 'Treileri', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(2, 'Kravas automašīnas', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(3, 'Teleskopiskie iekrāvēji', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(4, 'Ekskavatori', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(5, 'Iekrāvēji', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(6, 'Pacēlāji', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(7, 'Elektroiekārtas', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(8, 'Ģeneratori', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '7', 1, NULL),
(9, 'Strāvas kārbas', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '7', 1, NULL),
(10, 'Aprīkojums', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(11, 'Vibro blietes', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '10', 1, NULL),
(12, 'Ūdens pumpji', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '10', 1, NULL),
(13, 'Vinčas', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '10', 1, NULL),
(14, 'Gāzes sildītāji', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '10', 1, NULL),
(15, 'Plātņu satvērēji', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '10', 1, NULL),
(16, 'Celtniecības sastatnes', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', NULL, 0, NULL),
(17, 'Citi', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Error:

SQL error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (INSERT INTO `categories` (`id...
                                              ^
```

I checked SQL validity [here](http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/) and there was no errors found. I don't understand where is the issue ?

Maybe PostgreSQL version problems?

Based on your suggestions I changed my code to :

```
INSERT INTO "categories" ("id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "ancestry", "ancestry_depth", "priority") VALUES
(1, "Treileri", '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(2, "Kravas automašīnas", '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(3, "Teleskopiskie iekrāvēji", '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(4, "Ekskavatori", '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(5, "Iekrāvēji", '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(6, "Pacēlāji", '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(7, "Elektroiekārtas", '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(8, "Ģeneratori", '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '7', 1, NULL),
(9, "Strāvas kārbas", '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '7', 1, NULL),
(10, "Aprīkojums", '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(11, "Vibro blietes", '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '10', 1, NULL),
(12, "Ūdens pumpji", '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '10', 1, NULL),
(13, "Vinčas", '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '10', 1, NULL),
(14, "Gāzes sildītāji", '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '10', 1, NULL),
(15, "Plātņu satvērēji", '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '10', 1, NULL),
(16, "Celtniecības sastatnes", '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', NULL, 0, NULL),
(17, "Citi", '2014-09-24 17:45:03', '2014-09-24 17:45:03', NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Still the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: You are using backquotes with Postgres?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need the backticks at all. In some (rare) cases you might need double quotes in postgres. Mysql and SQLite's use of backticks is nonstandard. See this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573922/what-does-the-sql-standard-say-about-usage-of-backtick

Comment: Insert is OK. But why You do Select on it ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Please , see update, still the same error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character literals need to be enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes. Double quotes are for identifiers. `"Treileri"` is an identifier (e.g. a column name), `'Treileri'` is a character literal.

So you need to replace all double quotes for the values with single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO "categories" ("id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "ancestry", "ancestry_depth", "priority") VALUES
(1, 'Treileri', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
(2, 'Kravas automašīnas', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', '2014-09-24 17:45:02', NULL, 0, NULL),
.....
```

More details about identifiers and literals can be found in the manual:

- Identifiers: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS
- Character literals: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Working SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/87c23/1

---

If this is a new installation you should not use a version that is no longer maintained (=supported). 8.4 is really old. For a new installation you should go for 9.3 or 9.4