# Syntax error on date sort

Tags: sorting, date, ultralite

I am using Ultralite 12.  I have a table with a date field called "Date."  (I didn't name it.)  I want to sort my results by this field.

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM ItemHistory
where itemid = 'BC-2000-005' and customerid = '227B05'
```

works and returns the results

```
HistoryType,ItemID,UM_ID,CustomerID,Date,OrderHeaderID
1,'BC-2000-005',1,'227B05',2014-11-24,'849446-1'
1,'BC-2000-005',1,'227B05',2014-12-17,'852747-1'
1,'BC-2000-005',1,'227B05',2015-01-02,'854701-1'
1,'BC-2000-005',1,'227B05',2015-02-09,'859811-1'
```

I want to return the top answer when the results are sorted by date (in other words, the last one).

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM ItemHistory
where itemid = 'BC-2000-005' and customerid = '227B05'
order by date DESC
```

gives me a syntax error by DESC.  I've tried this as well:

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM ItemHistory
where itemid = 'BC-2000-005' and customerid = '227B05'
order by [date] DESC
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Try with "date". You could find more info from http://dev.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/db/sybase9/help/dbrfen9/00000010.htm

Comment: Do you want to emphasize that enclosing the column name in double quotes is the standard SQL way to indicate a 'delimited identifier', and a delimited identifier is the standard way of using a reserved word such as `date` as a column name (or table name, or …)?

Comment: In case of MySql it is ՝ . Im not that there is a standard.

Comment: There's a standard: double quotes.  There are abuses of the standard: just about every DBMS does that to some extent or another, except perhaps DB2.  See [What does the SQL standard say about usage of backtick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573922/), probably amongst other questions.