# Square Brackets and Quotation Marks in SQL

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to SQL.

In fact, I just started to use SQLite for Android.

I saw some SQLite examples and found some people using **""** and **[]**.

I tested those in my code and now I'm guessing they are just the same as **``**.

**1. Am I right?**

**2. If so, those are standard? I mean, can I use them in MySQL or Oracle too?**

I also tried "" instead of '' for column data and worked fine.

**3. Can I use double quotation marks for this use case? And standard?**

Comment: `""` is the standard for identifiers. sqlite also supports backticks and `[]` for compatibility with MySQL and MS SQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573922/what-does-the-sql-standard-say-about-usage-of-backtick

Comment: Thanks a lot laalto!

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard to encapsulate strings is **''**, on ALL RDBMS platforms.
**[** and **]** are used to escape spaces in columns (or indexes) or table (or view) names.

Comment: The SQL standard uses "..." to escape special characters in identifiers. [...] is a Microsoft extension.

Comment: @CL Thank you for the clarification. **[** and **]** also work in SQLite, though.

Comment: Only [for compatibility](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).