# Where do we use backticks and quotes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am new to SQL and still learning but one thing I am confused about is where we use `` ` `` and `'` operators in MySQL/MariaDB. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573922/what-does-the-sql-standard-say-about-usage-of-backtick

Comment: update you question and add  a proper sample  realted  to your question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Backticks (`` ` ``) are used to indicate database, table, and column names. Unless you're using reserved or conflicting words for table and database names, you'll not need to use them.

Quotes (`'` or `"`) are used to delimit strings, and differentiate them from column names.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE `column` = "value";
```

As I mentioned, backticks aren't needed, if you use reasonable table and column names:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.users WHERE username = "jim";
```

But strings will always need quotes. This query is comparing the value in the column `username` against a value in the column `bob`, rather than the string value "bob":

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.users WHERE username = bob;
```