# Correctly pass a db name having '-' in pymssql

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymssql

I have a db name which consists of a '-' (like dbName-2020). When I am trying to execute query I am getting following error:

```
pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near '-'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Here is code I used:

```
serverName = 'servername.com'
userName = 'user2'
passWord = 'pass2'
dbName = 'dbName-2020'
conn = pymssql.connect(serverName , userName , passWord, "tempdb")
cursor1 = conn.cursor()
db_query = "SELECT CONVERT(date,LastImportDate),* from "+dbName+"..tblStores WHERE run= %s"
query_result1 = cursor1.execute(db_query,('true'))
query_output = cursor1.fetchone()
```

Same code is working for all other databases. How can I pass a db name having '-'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use square bracket

```
dbName = '[dbName-2020]'
```

[What does the SQL Standard say about usage of backtick(`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573922/what-does-the-sql-standard-say-about-usage-of-backtick)