# How to insert a String into Oracle as a date type

Tags: java, oracle, date

I have a birthdate as string

```
String memBirthDate = "19990715";
```

and I tried to insert this into oracle by using query below.

```
<entry key="insertMember">
    INSERT INTO MEMBER
          (
       MEM_BIRTHDATE
           )
      VALUES (
            (TO_DATE)?
             )
           </entry>
```

But it doesn't work.  I think there's some problem in my oracle query but I'm not sure.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid legacy classes

Never use either `Date` class. Both are part of the terrible date-time legacy classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `LocalDate`

For a date-only value, use `LocalDate` class.

Your input string complies with the “basic” variation of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format, YYYYMMDD. So use the predefined formatter, [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```
String input = "19990715" ;
LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

Write your SQL like the following.

Tip: Use trailing underscore in all your database naming to avoid collision with reserved keywords. The SQL standard promises explicitly to never use a trailing underscore. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67351829/642706) by me.

Another tip: Use [text blocks](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378) for your embedded SQL code.

```java
String sql  =
        """
        INSERT INTO member_ ( id_ , birth_date_ ) 
        VALUES ( ? , ? ) 
        ;
        """;
```

Exchange the `LocalDate` object for writing to database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , birthDate ) ;
```

When retrieving the data value from the database.

```
LocalDate birthDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more. You will find complete source code for example apps that create a table, insert rows, and retrieve rows.

Comment: *"All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow"* and yet there's no duplicate? Either close as dupe, or if there is none then remove this statement. It makes indeed no sense to repeat the same thing over and over.